# WebGL: vec2 multiplied by 1 breaks texture coordinates

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I have got a texture bound to a framebuffer object so I can render to this texture. Because the canvas/viewport may be smaller than the texture, I multiply the texture coordinates by the current scale (`canvas size/texture size`) to get the correct position.

The line in the fragment shader to get the correct color from the texture looks as follows:

```
vec4 rtt = texture2D(rtt_sampler, v_texCoord * u_scale);
```

This works perfectly fine **but** if `u_scale` is exactly `1.0` everything breaks. I don't get the correct color but always the same, regardless the coordinates (it may be `0.5` but I haven't tested it yet). Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: It's unlikely that your texture coordinate scaling is the problem here.  You should check for errors (call `getError` from your WebGL context), verify that your framebuffer object is consistent (call `checkFramebufferStatus`), and make sure you've re-bound your texture after using it as a framebuffer attachment.  Also, you can adjust your viewport to match the texture size for rendering once it's attached to your FBO.

Comment: Changing the viewport to the original size before calling the draw to the texture did the trick, thank you :-) So the whole thing with scaling the texture coordinates became unnecessary.